# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' when using login function

Tags: flutter, parse-platform

the following method works fine, and i am able to register a new user on my parse based app backend

```
void doUserRegistration() async {

    final username = _textEditControllerEmailField.text.trim();
    final password = _textEditControllerPasswordField.text.trim();
    final user = ParseUser.createUser(username, password, username);

    var response = await user.signUp(allowWithoutEmail: true);

    if (response.success) {

      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('settingsPage', (route) => false);
    } else {
      showError(response.error!.message);
    }
  }
```

but this one fails with the error in the title above

```
 void doUserLogin() async {

    final username = _textEditControllerEmailField.text.trim();
    final password = _textEditControllerPasswordField.text.trim();
    var user1 =  ParseUser.createUser(username, password, username);

    var response = await user1.login();

    if (response.success) {

      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('settingsPage', (route) => false);
    } else {
      showError(response.error!.message);
    }
  }
```

can anyone help me understand why ? i checked https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk_flutter this page and the login calls listed there don't work either

Comment: thats meant your return value from backend is `null`. can you post `login()` code?

Comment: Your login function is not working. you are getting a null value in the responce that's why it's saying Null is not a subtype of int ( responce.sucess should be an int value) .Anyway you are not passing the username and password to the login flunction.

Comment: I can see that the plugin you are using does not have null safety, so the problem can be that `response` may has a `null` value causing this exception

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/issues/705